# Postgres stuck with `FATAL: the database system is starting up ` for hours. Should we wait or is this a sign for a corrupted DB?

Tags: postgresql

I found answers to this problem suggesting that it might take a while to restart postgres. But now we are already waiting for over 2 hours which seems extremely long compared to the 5 minutes it usually takes.
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922433/postgresql-fatal-the-database-system-is-starting-up-windows-10,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922433/postgresql-fatal-the-database-system-is-starting-up-windows-10
)

There are no other logs than `FATAL: the database system is starting up`.
Furthermore, the CPU and RAM utilization is minimal. It looks like nothing is happening.

We also checked disk space which is no problem.

How long should we wait until trying something else? And do you have any idea what could have caused this and how to fix it?

Some additional information:

- Postgres version is 13.8
- the size of the database is something in the range of 1.5TB
- if our monitoring works correctly the last checkpoint was around 20 minutes before the shutdown
- wal settings:

```
max_wal_size = 8GB
min_wal_size = 512MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
```

After starting postgres with the `-d 3` flag we got the following logs:

```
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.471 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.8 (Ubuntu 13.8-1.pgdg22.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, 64-bit
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.472 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.472 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.480 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.683 UTC [14] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2022-12-02 10:01:04 UTC
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.683 UTC [14] DEBUG:  removing all temporary WAL segments
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.914 UTC [1] DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=15 socket=9
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.915 UTC [15] LOG:  connection received: host=10.255.0.181 port=46576
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.918 UTC [15] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.918 UTC [15] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.918 UTC [15] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.918 UTC [15] DEBUG:  proc_exit(1): 1 callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.918 UTC [15] DEBUG:  exit(1)
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.918 UTC [15] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.918 UTC [15] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.918 UTC [15] DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:10.920 UTC [1] DEBUG:  server process (PID 15) exited with exit code 1
 2022-12-02 15:17:11.157 UTC [1] DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=16 socket=9
 2022-12-02 15:17:11.157 UTC [16] LOG:  connection received: host=10.255.0.181 port=56142
 2022-12-02 15:17:11.158 UTC [16] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
 2022-12-02 15:17:11.158 UTC [16] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:11.158 UTC [16] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:11.158 UTC [16] DEBUG:  proc_exit(1): 1 callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:11.158 UTC [16] DEBUG:  exit(1)
 2022-12-02 15:17:11.158 UTC [16] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:11.158 UTC [16] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:11.158 UTC [16] DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
 2022-12-02 15:17:11.160 UTC [1] DEBUG:  server process (PID 16) exited with exit code 1
```

This repeats indefinitely.

Using strace as Laurenz suggested gave us this:

```
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,463 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/pg_ctl-13.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,463 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/pg_ctl-13.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,463 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C/LC_MESSAGES/pg_ctl-13.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,463 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/pg_ctl-13.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,463 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/pg_ctl-13.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,463 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C/LC_MESSAGES/pg_ctl-13.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,464 PM] newfstatat(1, "", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,465 PM] write(1, "waiting for server to start...", 30waiting for server to start...) = 30
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,466 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/postgres/pgdata/data/postmaster.pid", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,466 PM] wait4(63, 0x7ffcc7ccd680, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,466 PM] write(1, ".", 1.)                        = 1
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,466 PM] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,515 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/postgres/pgdata/data/postmaster.pid", O_RDONLY) = 3
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,515 PM] newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=68, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,516 PM] read(3, "63\n/home/postgres/pgdata/data\n16"..., 69) = 68
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,517 PM] close(3)                                = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,518 PM] wait4(63, 0x7ffcc7ccd680, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,519 PM] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000}, NULL2022-12-02 16:25:50.604 UTC [63] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.8 (Ubuntu 13.8-1.pgdg22.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, 64-bit
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,540 PM] 2022-12-02 16:25:50.612 UTC [63] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,540 PM] 2022-12-02 16:25:50.612 UTC [63] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,546 PM] 2022-12-02 16:25:50.617 UTC [63] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,619 PM] ) = 0 (Timeout)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,619 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/postgres/pgdata/data/postmaster.pid", O_RDONLY) = 3
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,619 PM] newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=88, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,620 PM] read(3, "63\n/home/postgres/pgdata/data\n16"..., 89) = 88
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,621 PM] close(3)                                = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,621 PM] wait4(63, 0x7ffcc7ccd680, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,621 PM] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,716 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/postgres/pgdata/data/postmaster.pid", O_RDONLY) = 3
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,716 PM] newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=88, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,716 PM] read(3, "63\n/home/postgres/pgdata/data\n16"..., 89) = 88
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,716 PM] close(3)                                = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,717 PM] wait4(63, 0x7ffcc7ccd680, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,717 PM] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,817 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/postgres/pgdata/data/postmaster.pid", O_RDONLY) = 3
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,819 PM] newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=88, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,820 PM] read(3, "63\n/home/postgres/pgdata/data\n16"..., 89) = 88
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,824 PM] close(3)                                = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,824 PM] wait4(63, 0x7ffcc7ccd680, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,824 PM] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,918 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/postgres/pgdata/data/postmaster.pid", O_RDONLY) = 3
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,919 PM] newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=88, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,919 PM] read(3, "63\n/home/postgres/pgdata/data\n16"..., 89) = 88
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,919 PM] close(3)                                = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,919 PM] wait4(63, 0x7ffcc7ccd680, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,919 PM] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,019 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/postgres/pgdata/data/postmaster.pid", O_RDONLY) = 3
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,019 PM] newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=88, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,019 PM] read(3, "63\n/home/postgres/pgdata/data\n16"..., 89) = 88
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,020 PM] close(3)                                = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,020 PM] wait4(63, 0x7ffcc7ccd680, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,020 PM] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,120 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/postgres/pgdata/data/postmaster.pid", O_RDONLY) = 3
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,120 PM] newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=88, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,120 PM] read(3, "63\n/home/postgres/pgdata/data\n16"..., 89) = 88
```

So this is repeating

```
[02.12.2022, 5:25:50,919 PM] pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,019 PM] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/postgres/pgdata/data/postmaster.pid", O_RDONLY) = 3
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,019 PM] newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=88, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,019 PM] read(3, "63\n/home/postgres/pgdata/data\n16"..., 89) = 88
[02.12.2022, 5:25:51,020 PM] close(3)
```

Comment: Seems fishy. What do you get in the log file?

Comment: I added logs to the question

Comment: How exactly do you start postgres? `pg_ctl`? Please show the full command.

Comment: We are using this docker image https://hub.docker.com/layers/timescale/timescaledb-ha/pg13-ts2.7-oss-latest/images/sha256-f7608be13844eaca7140fdfd3e01a636753ac12ced99a050a6c07d7aaaa97273?context=explore which uses this command
`pg_ctl -D "$PGDATA" -o "$(printf '%q ' "$@")" -w start`

Comment: I would run an `strace` on the startup process and see what it is doing. Also, [taking a stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend) of the startup process would be useful.

Comment: That repeating message looks like PostgreSQL is trying to start, but there happened to be some process running whose process ID happened to be the same as in the `postmaster.pid` of the crashed instance, so it waited for that to finish, which it didn't. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: make sure you haven't run out of disk space

Answer (score 5):

The database is running again. We are not entirely sure why but that is what we did:

We figured out that while Postgres was starting we got a lot of

```
2022-12-02 15:17:10.918 UTC [15] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

which were error messages responding to a lot of client requests trying to reach the database. We started the database on another port so that it can start without all the clients trying to reach it. For some reason this fixed it (at least we think so). The database started normally and after shutting it down again and restarting it on the original port it is back in operation.

A scary experience ...

Comment: Each message with "the database is starting up" is new time postgres tried to start again. So if you get more than one of those you're probably in a loop and there's no point waiting any longer to try something new.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn this is actually logged any time a new connection to the database is made. That's what postgres tells the client, and then it aborts the connection.

Answer (score -1):

hot_standby is set to off
It's a normal behaviour in this case
when hot_standby is set to on, you can log in and the database is no longer "starting up"